# Arbitrary-length LIKE clause in Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm attempting to write a Ruby method which accepts an array of strings (for example, `["EG", "K", "C"]`, and returns all records from a database table where the `icao_code` field starts with any of those strings (for example, KORD, EGLL, and CYVR would all match). The length of the array will vary, and it will be input by a user, so it needs to be sanitized.

If I were only searching for a single string, I could do something like `Airport.where("icao_code LIKE ?", "#{icao_start}%")`. However, since I need to search against an arbitrary number of strings, I can't use that syntax.

Right now, I've got it working as follows:

```
def in_region(icao_starts)
  where_clause = icao_starts.map{|i| "icao_code LIKE '#{i}%'"}.join(" OR ")
  return Airport.where(where_clause)
end
```

However, I'm a bit worried using a setup like this with untrusted user input, since I suspect it would be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Is there a better way to get the same result in a more secure way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider something like this:

```
def in_region(icao_starts)
  where_clause = "icao_code LIKE '#?%' OR " * icao_starts.length
  return Airport.where(where_clause.sub(/\ OR\ $/, ''), *icao_starts)
end
```

This will build up a (potentially very long?) string with `?` placeholders. The `*icao_starts` will expand that array into arguments to the where clause, so each `?` will end up getting safely replaced. The `sub(/\ OR\ $/, '')` simply trims off the final `OR` (you could append `1=0` instead if you wanted).

If I were you I would also perform a `.uniq` on `icao_starts` before you do anything, truncate the array at some sensible upper length limit, <s>and also have a whitelist of permitted values</s> (oh, forget that, I thought users were searching by airport code). That should be pretty much infallible.

Comment: Ended up using `compact` and `uniq`. I also did a `map{|s| s.upcase.tr{"^A-Z","")}` to deal with users entering lowercase letters and to remove any non-alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about not interpolating user input into your SQL query. This is dangerous and makes your code vulnerable for SQLI attacks.

```
def in_region(icao_starts)
  conditions = icao_starts.map { "icao_code LIKE ?"}
  Airport.where(conditions.join(' OR '), *icao_starts.map { |name| "#{name}%"})
end
```

It is pretty similar than the solution of bogardpd but does not use a Regexp to get rid of the last " OR"